# Angular2 Input value property is not refreshed properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have a form with possibility of adding various number of fields. There is a problem with displaying a proper values of previous fields when adding a new one - every field is reset to default value, seems like value property of input is not working correctly
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS1vC.jpg)

You can see that value is binded properly (text on the right side of Name field), but during creating "new column" all input fields are reset to default value.

HTML:

```
<div class="container col-8 top-buffer">
    <form #newTableForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Table Name">Table Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-10" id="tableName" name="tableName" [(ngModel)]="tableWrapper.table.name" placeholder="Example Name">
        </div>
    <label for="Columns">Columns</label>
    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let column of tableWrapper.columns; let i = index ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="nameAddon">Name</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="column.name" #name="ngModel" name="name" value = {{column.name}} >{{column.name}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="typeAddon" >Type</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="column.type" #name="ngModel" name="type" value = {{column.type}} >
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-auto">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" (click) = "deleteColumn(i)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    <button type="submit" (click) = "moveUp(i)" class="btn btn-info">Up</button>
                    <button type="submit" (click) = "moveDown(i)" class="btn btn-info">Down</button>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" (click) = "addColumn()" class="btn btn-success ">Add Column</button>
        <button type="submit" (click) = "display()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Table</button>
    </div> 
    </form>
</div>
```

Component:

```
import { Column } from './../common/Column';
import { TableWrapper } from './../common/TableWrapper';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    template: require('app/creator/createTable.component.html!text')
})
export class CreateTableComponent implements OnInit {
    tableWrapper: TableWrapper;
    name: string;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.tableWrapper = new TableWrapper();
        this.tableWrapper.columns.push(new Column());
    }

    addColumn() {
        this.tableWrapper.columns.push(new Column());
    }

    deleteColumn(index: number) {
        this.tableWrapper.columns.splice(index, 1);
    }

    moveUp(index: number){
        if(index !== 0) {
        [ this.tableWrapper.columns[index], this.tableWrapper.columns[index - 1] ] =
        [ this.tableWrapper.columns[ index - 1 ], this.tableWrapper.columns[index] ];
        }
    }

     moveDown(index: number){
        if(index !== this.tableWrapper.columns.length - 1) {
        [ this.tableWrapper.columns[index], this.tableWrapper.columns[index + 1] ] =
        [ this.tableWrapper.columns[ index + 1 ], this.tableWrapper.columns[index] ];
        }
    }

    display(){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.tableWrapper));
    }

    getNameByIndex(index: number): string {
        return this.tableWrapper.columns[index].name;
    }

}
```

TableWrapper:

```
import { Table } from './Table';
import { Column } from './Column';
export class TableWrapper {
    table: Table;
    columns: Array<Column>;

    constructor(){
        this.table = new Table();
        this.columns = new Array();
    }
}
```

Column:

```
export class Column {
    id: number;
    tableId: number;
    name: string;
    type: string;

    constructor(){
        this.name = 'Example Name';
        this.type = 'Example Type';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have a form, on which you use the same `name` attribute for all your formfields for array, which will then be evaluated as the one and same value. `[(ngModel)]` will be overridden in this case. When you give your name attributes unique names, your code will work as you want. The easiest way is to make use of the index of the values in the array, and assign that to your name attribute. So for column name, it would be the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let column of tableWrapper.columns; let i = index ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="column.name" #name="ngModel" name="name{{i}}" value = {{column.name}} >{{column.name}}
</div>
```

Here's a

### **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jAdKD5pYcx4Mu3u0n7Yn?p=preview)**

with column names and types working :)